# Compile time effect of several redeclarations?

Tags: c++

Maybe this question sounds silly, but is there any compile time overhead associated with multiple declarations (in this case very useless ones) of the same name in the same declarative region, like:
(Thanks to the ones who pointed out that I was using wrong code, forgot that I was re*defining* names, so here is an updated version):

```
class X;
class X;
class X;
class X;
class X;
//And much more of those
int main()
{
}
```

How would this affect the compilation?

Comment: Is this the result of auto-generated code?

Comment: Wow this ruins the actual question.. Anyway, I have now updated the code to show some redeclarations rather than redefinitions.

Comment: With reference to your updated question, how many million forward declarations of `class X` were you thinking of typing in?

Comment: It will not compile any faster, right? But compared to the 300.000 lines you would get from things like `#include "windows.h"`, any difference would likely be insignificant.

Comment: @BoPersson Well so just theoretically, if you for some reason had 300.000 lines of redeclarations of the same entity, it could affect compile time? If so, why? You might be able to save my day :))))))

Answer (score 1):

[It simply won't compile.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition)

> Only one definition of any variable, function, class type, enumeration type, concept (since C++20) or template is allowed in any one translation unit (some of these may have multiple declarations, but only one definition is allowed).

Comment: Yes, I know... I accidentally copied the wrong code.. But it is updated now :=)